# List of possible tags that are synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

This is to list tags that may possibly be synonyms:

[asp.net](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) = [aspx](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aspx)

[blog](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog) = [blogs](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blogs)

[browser](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser) = [browsers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browsers)

[customer-service](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customer-service) = [customer-support](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customer-support)

[dns-server](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dns-server) = [dns-servers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dns-servers)

[domain-name](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain-name) = [domain-names](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain-names)

[font](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font) = [fonts](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts)

[form](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form) = [forms](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forms)

[forum](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forum) = [forums](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forums)

[heading](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heading) = [headings](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headings)

[htm5](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htm5) = [html5](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html5)

[map](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map) = [maps](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maps)

[nameserver](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nameserver) = [nameservers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nameservers)

Comment: I disagree with the first, btw; asp.net <> aspx - subtle, maybe, and it depends on whether the difference is important for your audience (it matters lots on stackoverflow, for example - different audience)

Comment: @marc, that's why I held off as I wasn't sure if all of these actually synonyms or just similar. Your input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More for consideration:

[organization](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organization) = [organizations](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organizations)

[recommendation](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendation) = [recommendations](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations)

[redirect](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redirect) = [redirects](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redirects)

[search-engine](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-engine) = [search-engines](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-engines)

[sites](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sites) = [sites](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sites)

[stats](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stats) = [statistics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics)

[suggestion](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggestion) = [suggestions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggestions)

[tld](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tld) = [top-level-domain](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/top-level-domain)

[url](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url) = [urls](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urls)

[user](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user) = [users](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/users)

[web-application](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-application) = [web-applications](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-applications) = [web-apps](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apps)

[web-crawler](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-crawler) = [web-crawlers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-crawlers)

[webhosting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webhosting) = [web-hosting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-hosting)

[web-service](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-service) = [web-services](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-services)

[website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website) = [websites](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/websites)

Comment: this is now complete -- merging and synonymizing can be done in one swell foop now.

Comment: @jeff, sounds good. I'll be sure to try it all out on the synonyms above

Comment: well, I already merged them -- I was just indicating both a) completeness of task and b) improvement of tools

Comment: @jeff, in that case thank you on both fronts :)

Answer (score 4):

ok, I set up these synonyms and merged.

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=newest

Remember that anyone can *suggest* a synonym from the tag info page, that is:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags/apache/info

from here, click on the **synonyms** tab.

Comment: thanks Jeff. I got about halfway through the tags when I stopped so there should be a few more coming shortly.

Comment: It says this "Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms."

Comment: @melanie no worries; add a new answer here with proposed synonyms and John or I can merge them.

Answer (score 3):

here's another:

[host](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/host) = [hosting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hosting)

Answer (score 2):

I've proposed that [hosting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hosting) be merged with [web-hosting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-hosting). Feel free to vote. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms